# repeated modules in "node_modules" of each module

Tags: node.js, npm

How i can solve the problem of duplicated modules that each modules need? I have 3 modules that in their own "node_modules" have the request module, and each in diferent version.

Maybe using npm install -g, npm download only one.

But if I use this, the same for all, maybe make problems with correct use of version, or not.

NPM solve this? Make diferents folders of versions in global folder of node_modules??
Thanks.

Comment: Why does it matter? The vast majority of packages are pretty small so shouldn't cause any problems with size.

Comment: I can think of lots of ways of do it dirty or messy or manual, but I'm curious of read a proper answer :D. Though I can't see to be worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

npm has an experimental(!) feature for that:

```
npm dedupe
```

(see `npm help dedupe` for an explanation)

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly how NPM was designed.

The idea behind this is that each module is *self contained*, what means that they should not depend on higher dependencies, everything it needs is inside its directory.
Imagine the following scenario:

- A depends on B, version range 1.3.x
- C depends on B, minimum version 2.1.0

If NPM wasn't designed the way it was, handling such situation wouldn't be an easy task.

Also, you can't `require()` global modules.

However, you can try to reduce duplication of modules by using the [`npm dedupe`](https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-dedupe.html) command - it will try to simplify the complex tree of modules for you.